# How to handle offline authentication in PWAs without third-party services and address compatibility issues with Firefox's caching behavior?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, vite

I'm developing a Progressive Web App (PWA) that operates offline, serving cached decks and cards successfully. However, I'm facing challenges with the initial authentication when the user enters the app. The app makes a request to /getuser, but if the user is offline, it can't authenticate.

I've currently implemented a solution where I cache the /getuser request to retrieve authentication information from the cache. However, I'm unsure if this is a secure and industry-level approach. Additionally, this strategy is not working as expected in Firefox, although it functions fine in Chrome. What would be a more secure and industry-standard way to handle offline authentication in PWAs without any third party services? Is caching the /getuser request a recommended approach, and how can I address the compatibility issues with Firefox?

In Firefox, if the user's session expires, it stores that in cache. Even if the user is online and logged in, it keeps serving that cached data, causing the logged-in user to redirect to the session expired page, even if my cache strategy is network first. It works as expected in Chrome. Chrome serves cached data only when the user is offline.

I am using the vite-plugin-pwa library to add service workers and handle all the caching

Here is my code:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import { VitePWA } from "vite-plugin-pwa";


export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  // In vite.config.ts we can't access env variables using import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL we have to use following code to access it.
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd())
  const API_URL = `${env.VITE_API_URL}`

  return {
    plugins: [react(), VitePWA({

      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true
      },
      injectRegister: 'auto',
      // add this to cache all the imports
      workbox: {
        globDirectory: "dist",
        globPatterns: ["**/*",],
        runtimeCaching: [
          {

            urlPattern: new RegExp(`${API_URL}/decks$`), //  your API endpoint
            handler: 'NetworkFirst', //  caching strategy 
            options: {
              cacheName: 'decks-cache',
              expiration: {
                maxEntries: 1, // number of entries to store
                maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // cache expiration time
              },
              cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [200]
              }

            },

          },
          {
            urlPattern: new RegExp(`${API_URL}/cards/.+`),
            handler: 'NetworkFirst', // Caching strategy for /cards/deck_id
            options: {
              cacheName: 'cards-cache',
              expiration: {
                maxEntries: 500,
                maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // cache expiration time
              },
              cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [200],
              },
            },

          },
          {
            urlPattern: new RegExp(`${API_URL}/decks-and-cards$`),
            handler: 'NetworkFirst',
            options: {
              cacheName: 'search-cache',
              expiration: {
                maxEntries: 500,
                maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // cache expiration time
              },
              cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [200],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            urlPattern: new RegExp(`${API_URL}/getuser$`),
            handler: 'NetworkFirst',
            options: {
              cacheName: 'auth-cache',
              expiration: {
                maxEntries: 500,
                maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // cache expiration time
              },
              cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [200],
              },
            },
          },
        ]
      },
      // add this to cache all the
      // static assets in the public folder
      includeAssets: [
        "**/*",
      ],
      manifest: {
        ....
     }
    }),],
  }
})
```